# Installshield: how to add Java run-time environment?

Tags: java, installshield

Using Installshield, how can I include the Java JRE as part of the package?

Answer (score 1):

use an [prerequisite](http://kb.flexerasoftware.com/doc/Helpnet/installshield16helplib_sp1/DesigningRedist.htm)